# Get the Values of an Object's Attributes from Module Methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

I'm building a module like the one below but I'm getting an 'undefined method' error on the self.attributes method call. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't see it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
module TestModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.extend(InstanceMethods)
  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def mon_mothma
      self.attributes.each do |key, value|
        admiral_ackbar(key)
      end
    end

  end

  module ClassMethods

    def admiral_ackbar(key)
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end

  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, TestModule)
```

Comment: Where is the `attributes` method defined?

Comment: I think the attributes method is defined in the ActiveRecord class although I wasn't able to confirm that. I know if you instantiate an ActiveRecord object then attributes is an instance method on the object. Does that help?

Comment: I think it should be `base.include(InstanceMethods)` as `extend` will make these class methods (like you are doing with ClassMethods) and `attributes` is not a class method.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I do `base.include(InstanceMethods)` then I can't call `mon_mothma` from my model because it's an instance method. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to call `mon_mothma` from a model and be able to get the attributes of the instantiated object.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking more about your feedback, I found my solution by changing `base.extend(InstanceMethods)` to `base.include(InstanceMethods)` as suggested. The instance methods were then available on the instantiated objects. Then I simply changed the troublesome class methods to instance methods. Thanks so much!